# Can we use came for feature

Tags: tense, verbs, present-tense

The other day, me and my friend argued about something we both not sure if it’s correct or not, he answered my phone call and spoke to my cousin, my cousin asked about me, “where is mouhanad”, my friend replayed, he is washing the car, when he came I’ll let him call you back”, is it correct to say “when he come I’ll let him call you back or when he came I’ll let him call you back?

I told my friend, by saying CAME it becomes past tense and you are talking about the close feature, Came will not be used for the feature, we have to use come instead.

I’m sorry for the mess above, please find the correct answer and explain for us,

Thank you
Mouhanad

Comment: You are correct that you should use the present tense, but the proper third-person present is "he **comes**", not "he **come**".

Answer (score 1):

You are right: *came* is past. What you want is *when he **comes***. (not "when he come": 3rd person - *he* - requires the *-s* form in the present).

Some corrections to your question:

> replayed -> replied

> feature -> future

> *let him call you back* is grammatical, but doesn't mean what you intend. It means "allow him to call you back". You want *get him to call you back* (informal), or _ask him to call you back (a little more formal).

Comment: I think it will be "tell" instead of "let". I mean it is his friend, not a baby that the parent will let them call someone. Just a suggestion I thought.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer, I appreciate it, and sorry for the mistakes that appeared in my question earlier.

Comment: Hello again, I shared your answer with my friend and he is still insisting, he said ask them by saying “future past tense”, is there something like that? Future past tense? And does it make ‘when he came’ be right?

Comment: No. What your friend is probably thinking of is the so-called "future in the past" in **indirect** speech. For example (direct) "When he **comes** I **will** get him to call you back" -> (indirect) "I said that when he **came** I **would** get him to call you back". Your example is direct speech, so does not do that backshifting.